# Best way to handle Braintree timeouts

Tags: ruby, api, payment-gateway, braintree

I have an app in ruby that process payments through Braintree but We have experienced stalled Braintree responses. This is our minimum viable product so a lot of things are not fully implemented and we are not leveraging the Braintree API at full.

Well basically a few customers have complained that the browser hangs and It is definitely a Braintree not responding issue. I haven't found any info on timeout handling on the BT docs. Hope the question isn't too broad. My main concern is Braintree processing the payment and the app not being notified.

Comment: Are you currently using any type of queueing or background job functionality to process the API calls?

Comment: No, by now I am taking the most naive approach: processing everything in the request, the traffic is low right now.

Comment: I am currently noticing this during development in my sandbox. Occasionaly the request runs into a "*connection timed out*"-error while I fetch the customer's payment method for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the API calls to Braintree are taking too long, contact Braintree support for assistance. It's their problem.

I don't know how you access the API, but most libraries allow you to set timeouts on requests. Check the docs for yours.